# build graphical user interface for command prompt run tools

Tags: user-interface, cmd, command-prompt

I have a tools which can be run by giving commands in command prompt window. I am using operating system Windows 7. I am interested to build a graphical user interface for the tools so that users don't require to open command prompt window to run the tools. Please guide me what I have to do for the same i.e to build a GUI for the tool?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you need to buy a book on programming and read up a little on the subject.  Most likely you'll need to use some kind of user friendly RAD (Rapid Application Development) tool like Visual Basic or Runtime Revolution to knock up a GUI. Consider that your tool will need to read in a configuration file describing your command line tools, their paths and parameters, and then draw UI elements onto the screen programatically as appropriate. All the best!

Comment: You're in luck as Microsoft did most of the work. Why not go and see what they already provide?

Comment: hmm, I shall try this out then...Thanks...

Comment: Penteract [CMD GUI Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/penteract-cmd-gui-creator/9mswmfz9xv2f?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to write a GUI using Visual Studio (you can easily google a tutorial, I found [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php) one), and you can run system commands using the `system()` function in cstdlib ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/))

If you're familiar with python, there are plenty of [GUI packages](https://docs.python.org/2/library/othergui.html), and you can use `os.system` to run system commands.

Basically, pick your language and google "GUI in ______" and "system commands in ______"